# How to sort a dictionary in a list using comparison to another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm working on a bigger program and need to sort a list of dictionaries. I'm using the integer values from a separate list and comparing them to the values associated with a specific key in each dictionary. I'm getting messed up results with this, and I have no idea why... help!

My code:

```
    new_list_of_dictionaries = []
    b = [{1: 'one', 'sam': '2,300'}, {3: 'thee', 'sam': '4,000'}]
    list_of integers = [2300, 2300]

    for i in list_sof_integers:

        for a_dictionary in b:
            r = a_dictionary["sam"].replace(',','')
            #print r
            #r2 = r.replace(',','')
            #print r2

            if i == int(r):
                new_list_of_dictionaries.append(a_dictionary)

            print new_list_of_dictionaries
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are filtering the list of dictionaries based on the numbers in the separate list. You can use list comprehension, with the filtering condition like this

```
[c_dict for c_dict in b if int(c_dict["sam"].replace(',','')) in list_of_ints]
```

The `in` operator will look for the integer value, in the `list_of_ints`. If you want to speed it up, you can convert the `list_of_ints` to a set, like this

```
set_of_ints = set(list_of_ints)
[c_dict for c_dict in b if int(c_dict["sam"].replace(',','')) in set_of_ints]
```